# How I can show only the logged user in SharePoint "Person or Group" List Item without Code

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, person-or-group

I want to create a Meeting Organization List which users can assign themselves in a meeting with available dates.
But when I create the column with the type "Person or Group" it is open for everybody and users can assign another user by typing their name. I want to prevent that.

I could not find any option to cancel it and I can not use SharePoint Designer so I can not write any type of code.

Can you help me?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Can you use InfoPath?

Comment: @SohailShaikh Yes I can use it

Answer (score 0):

You could use InfoPath forms to achieve this.

Just query the User Information List to make the data connection and rules to set the people picker field.

[Refer](https://wonderlaura.com/2012/06/27/infopath-pre-populate-the-people-picker/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try either of the following solutions

1. you can hide the user related column in the new form by adding script editor web

> $("input[title='UserColumn']").closest("tr").hide();

2. you can also check if the user id entered is same as the logged in user email or not by using presaveaction

> function presaveaction() 
>   {
>
> if($(".sp-peoplepicker-userSpan").attr("sid").split('|')[2]).toString()===_spPageContextInfo.userEmail.toString())
>
> { return true;
>    } 
>   else
>    { 
>   return false;
>    }
>    }